# TIdMBCSEncoding.Create('ASCII') returns with MaxCharSize = 0 on Linux

Tags: linux, delphi, indy, freepascal, iconv

My environment is Ubuntu 12.04 Linux on i386. I can see that only UTF-8 locales are installed (in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`):

```
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
~
```

Now the problem:

TIdIOHandler.InitComponent calls TIdTextEncoding.Default which in turn calls **TIdMBCSEncoding.Create('ASCII')**.

And there, the line

```
FMaxCharSize := GetByteCount(PWideChar(@cValue[0]), 2);
```

is executed, and GetByteCount returns zero - which should not happen (the expected value is 1 because ASCII is a single-byte encoding).

The place which returns the zero value is line 2288 in IdGlobal:

```
if iconv(FFromUTF16, @LCharsPtr, @LCharCount, @LBytesPtr, {$IFNDEF KYLIX}@{$ENDIF}LByteCount) = size_t(-1) then
begin
  Result := 0;
  Exit;
end;
```

Could this be caused by a missing UTF-16 locale? (I did not succeed installing UTF-16 support in my first attempt and maybe this problem has been seen by other Indy users on Linux too)

Comment: Have you checked the value of errno? http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.3.html

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff not yet, many thanks for the hint! (I will try it tomorrow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indy does not currently do adequate handling of `iconv()` errors because `iconv()` relies on platform-specific `errno` variables that are hard to implement in Indy across multiple platforms (this would not have been a problem if `iconv()` has been implemented to return its own error codes direcgtly).  Not all `iconv()` errors are real failures, but Indy does not know that yet, so it treats all errors as failures (as for why `GetByteCount()` returns 0 on failure instead of raising an exception, this is because `TIdTextEncoding` is modeled after Embarcadero's `SysUtils.TEncoding` class and thus has to be API-compatible with it.  This will change in Indy 11).

ICONV is supposed to implement its charsets natively, so it shouldn't matter what locates are installed in the OS.  In this case, I suspect that `iconv()` is failing to convert codepoint `$10FFFD` from UTF-16 to ASCII in `TIdMBCSEncoding.Create()` since it is outside the ASCII range, and this is one of those cases where Indy needs to look at `errno` to diffrentiate between a failure and partial conversion, but currently is not doing so.

As a workaround, you can edit IdGlobal.pas to have the `TIdTextEncoding.Default` property getter use the `TIdASCIIEncoding` class instead of the `TIdMBCSEncoding` class, since Indy has its own ASCII implementation that is not dependant on ICONV.

```
{$IFDEF HAS_CLASSPROPERTIES}
class function TIdTextEncoding.GetDefault: TIdTextEncoding;
{$ELSE}
class function TIdTextEncoding.Default: TIdTextEncoding;
{$ENDIF}
var
  LEncoding: TIdTextEncoding;
begin
  if GIdDefaultEncoding = nil then
  begin
    {$IFDEF USE_ICONV}
    //LEncoding := TIdMBCSEncoding.Create('ASCII');
    LEncoding := TIdASCIIEncoding.Create;
    {$ELSE}
    ...
```

Comment: Another alternative you might try is `TIdMBCSEncoding.Create('')` instead.  The empty string should tell iconv to use a machine/OS-dependant locale, which is really what `TIdTextEncoding.Default` is meant to represent anyway. But I suspect that there may be cases where even that can cause a similar failure in `GetByteCount()`.

Comment: Or maybe also try setting the charset name to `'ASCII//TRANSLIT'` instead of just `'ASCII'` by itself.

Comment: I just checked in a new version of IdGlobal.pas into Indy's SVN.  When iconv is enabled, it declares new  `GIdIconvUseLocaleDependantAnsiEncoding`, `GIdIconvIgnoreIllegalChars`, and `GIdIconvUseTransliteration` global variables, and updates the `TIdMBCSEncoding` constructor to raise an exception when `FMaxCharSize` cannot be calculated.

Comment: Setting GIdIconvUseTransliteration to True fixed it, many thanks!